# CreateCompatibleDC() failure

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, winapi, graphics, gdi+

I'm using win32 for 2D animation. My program so far loads an array of HBITMAP objects created from resource. The problem arises during animation when calling CreateCompatibleDC() from "OnUpdate()" in code below. AFTER MANY CALLS to the OnUpdate function, the HDC object is not created(possibly not allocated in memory). This causes unexpected results when DeleteDC() is called to delete the HDC object. Here is the update function code from main.cpp:

```
    void OnUpdate(
             HWND hwnd)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd,&ps);
    if(!hdc)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed to Create Compatible DC - 'hdc' in OnUpdate()", L"ALERT", MB_OK);
        PostMessage(hwnd, WM_DESTROY, NULL, NULL);
    }
    HPALETTE hpalT = SelectPalette(hdc,hpal,FALSE);

    BITMAP bm;
    HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    if(!hdcMem)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed to CreateCompatibleDC - 'hdcMem' in OnUpdate()", L"ALERT", MB_OK);
        PostMessage(hwnd, WM_DESTROY, NULL, NULL);
    }
    SelectBitmap(hdcMem, bkgMain);
    GetObject(bkgMain, sizeof(bm), &bm);
    BitBlt(backDC, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    // Clean up.
    if(!DeleteDC(hdcMem))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed to DeleteDC - 'hdcMem' in OnUpdate()", L"ALERT", MB_OK);
        PostMessage(hwnd, WM_DESTROY, NULL, NULL);
    }
    SelectPalette(hdc,hpalT,FALSE);
    EndPaint(hwnd,&ps);
}
```

Comment: What's the value of `GetLastError()` immediately after `CreateCompatibleDC` fails?

Comment: Are you sure about that?  Are you sure you're calling & saving the result of `GetLastError` *immediately* after `CreateCompatibleDC` returns `NULL`?  Because if you accidentally call any other WinAPI function (such as for logging etc.), it's quite likely that the last error code will get reset to 0.

Comment: does this error indicate an invalid handle? what causes an invalid handle?

Comment: Error 6 is `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`, which suggests you're passing in an invalid `HDC` as the input parameter to `CreateCompatibleDC`, which suggests that `BeginPaint` is returning an invalid handle, which seems rather unlikely.  Are you sure that `BeginPaint` is succeeding?  Because you have the same message box text in both of the cases where `BeginPaint` fails and where `CreateCompatibleDC` fails.

Comment: the messagebox indicates that "hdcMem" failed. not BeginPaint. I am Blting to a BACKBUFFER DC before Blting to the window's DC.

Comment: So, if I read your question correctly, the code you've shown works fine until after you've called it many times? In that case, it's almost certain the problem is that you're leaking GDI objects. And you most certainly are; you need to make sure that the creation of every GDI object is followed by releasing or destroying it when you're finished.

Comment: The `CreateCompatibleDC` function is not broken. I can't actually tell if anything is leaked because presumably your objects are being destroyed elsewhere, in code that isn't shown.

Comment: they are created in a function that is only called once, then destroyed when the program exits.

Comment: it was a GDI BRUSH object I was using to clear the screen in a different function

Comment: @Deanna I assume that `SelectBitmap()` is the macro defined in `WindowsX.h`. It's just a call to `SelectObject()`, but it casts the second `HBITMAP` parameter to an `HGDIOBJ` and the return value to `HBITMAP`.

Comment: But it doesn't appear that this code is keeping track of the return values from the `SelectXxx` functions when GDI objects are initially selected into device contexts. You need to re-select those objects back in after you're done, before you destroy the DC. Again, it's very hard to debug code that exists in functions we can't see.

Comment: @CodyGray: Ah, I only looked at the MSDN library rather than the headers. Google didn't give much useful info on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is `SelectBitmap()`?
If it's a wrapper/alias for [`SelectObject()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162957%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) then you're leaking a bitmap.

```
SelectBitmap(hdcMem, bkgMain);
```

You should select the old bitmap back into the DC before deleting it:

> This function returns the previously selected object of the specified
>   type. An application should always replace a new object with the
>   original, default object after it has finished drawing with the new
>   object.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and found it was caused by calling CreateCompatibleDC from WM_CREATE (before my main window was created).  I found GetDC(hwnd) gave me a HDC for the main window, but it could not be used until WM_CREATE was finished.  I relocated my code to WM_PAINT and my code worked well.